# CollectionAccumulator dependency is not resolving in Intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am new to Scala and Spark. I am writing a sample program on CollectionAccumulator. But the dependency for the CollectionAccumulator is not resolving in Intellij.

```
val slist : CollectionAccumulator[String] = new CollectionAccumulator()
sc.register(slist,"Myslist")
```

Please find the piece of code used. I tried the Accumulator[String] by replacing the CollectionAccumulator[String]. The Accumulator is getting resolved

I have imported the following:

```
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.{Accumulator, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.util._
```

Dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Scala and Spark dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0-cdh5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help..

Comment: what does your sbt look like?

Comment: I am using the maven for resolving dependency. I have updated the question with the pom.xml dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CollectionAccumulator are supported in spark 2.0+ version. You are on spark 1.2.0 cdh version. 
Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator

Replace your spark dependency with

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.cloudera1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also make sure that "${scala.version}" resolves to scala 2.11

Answer (score 1):

`CollectionAccumulator` comes only after [spark v2.0.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/AccumulatorV2.scala), simply update your spark version to [`2.0+`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10)

example `build.sbt`

```
name := "smartad-spark-songplaycount"                                                                                                                                           

version := "1.0"                                                                                       

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"                                                                               

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.0.0"                                

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0"                                 

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.2.0"                                   

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

example sbt console on above `.sbt`

```
sbt console

scala> import org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator
import org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator

scala> val slist : CollectionAccumulator[String] = new CollectionAccumulator()
slist: org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator[String] = Un-registered Accumulator: CollectionAccumulator
```